# Win32_StartupCommand not showing all entries?

Tags: powershell, wmi, startup

If I run 'System Configuration' (msconfig.exe) on my system, I see three entries.

- Parallels Tools
- Java   and
- Dropbox

[image: Screenshot of msconfig.exe]

But if I run the following powershell script:

```
$computer = "LocalHost" 
$namespace = "root\CIMV2" 
$results = Get-WmiObject -class Win32_StartupCommand -computername $computer -namespace $namespace
```

I only get the dropbox entry. Shouldn't the Win32_StartupCommand show all of the entries?
[image: Powershell]

Comment: The `Win32_StartupCommand` WMI class list the entries of the `\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` key, so check the contents of this key.

Comment: In my case, I also find the ones of the startup menus.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, the ones comming from `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` are not listed by `Win32_StartupCommand`.

Comment: Yes, but I'm trying to figure out why, and how to get them to appear.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ghacks.net/2016/06/04/windows-automatic-startup-locations/

This blog said the following two address are only in 64-bit system.

HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run (only on 64-bit systems)
HKCU\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run (only on 64-bit systems)

So I think you have to include them in your code as well.